# Como configurar docker compose com equivalente para opção -d (detach)

Tags: docker

O seguinte comando roda um container com mysql no background.

```
docker run -d -p 3306:3306 -e MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes --name mysqldb mysql
```

O equivalente com o `docker-compose.yml` seria:

```
version: '2'

services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: yes
```

Mas quando eu rodo usando `docker-compose up` o processo fica no foreground. Como faço para adicionar o equivalente da opção detach (`-d`) do `docker container run`?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar o comando: `docker-compose up -d`. Esse comando inicia os containers em segundo plano e os deixa em execução. Saiba mais na documentação do Docker https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/.

Comment: Mas não tem jeito de indicar isso no docker-compose.yml, não é?